# Python multiprocessing : progress report from processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have some tasks in an application that are CPU bound and I want to use the multiprocessing module to use the multi-cores processors.
I take a big task (a video file analysis) and I split it into several smaller tasks which are put in a queue and done by worker processes.
What I want to know is how to report progress to the main process from these worker processes. For example I need them to send "I am at 1000ms of my analysis of file 1". What is the best way to do such progress reports ?

Comment: Are you asking about using the `logging` module?

Comment: No, I want progress report from the worker processes for use in the main process. I use the "multiprocessing" module.

Comment: Progress report from the worker processes for use in the main process can be done through the `logging` module.  Why do you say it can't be done?

Comment: Oh sorry if I misunderstood you. Could you please give an example of this technique ? I would be interested to see how it works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend a [multiprocessing.Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue): nothing easier than for the worker processes to post their updates (presumably as tuples with the various aspect of their progress updates) there, while the main process just wait for such messages and when they come updates the GUI (or textual UI;-) to keep the user appraised of progress.

Comment: Thanks. I think that it is the easiest solution. I'm currently implementing it and I'll ask again if something goes wrong. Sorry but I can't vote up your post because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @Marc, I believe that with 11 or more (and I see you're at 18) you _can_ upvote.  If it doesn't work for you you might want to ask on meta!